# VIM user defined function mapping doesn't work as I expected

Tags: function, dictionary, vim, call

I wish when I edit some source file under a directory, press  will trigger cmake and make build, like below:

```
command -bang -nargs=? Umake call Myfunction(<bang>0)
function! Myfunction(forced)
    lcd %:p:h
    call system('cmake && make')
endfunction
nmap <F5> :Umake<cr>
```

This code snippet is copied from internet and did a bit modification, not very sure if it's totally OK. After re-enter vim, Press , the left-bottom command windows shows ":Su" and nothing happened.

(1) Why nothing happened, any syntax issue in Myfunction?
(2) Is the line "command -bang" necessary? What's the meaning of 0 here?

Thanks.

Comment: `<bang>0` means either `!0` which is `1` or `0` which check the presence of a bang (i.e `Umake` or `Umake!`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to compile with `system()`

Set instead `:let &makeprg = 'cd "compilation/dir" && make $*'`. Then `:make target -j 12`.

Again, build-tool-wrappers plugin already handles out-of-source tree compilation (with multiple compilation directories), target detection, background compilation...